# JQuery hide last next button in Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I was using bootstrap tabs to view my content, and inside each tabs there is a next and previous button to navigate through each tabs, and this is my HTML :

```
<div class="nav nav-thumb" id="thumb-tabs" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-thumb active" id="1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#thumb-item-1" role="tab" aria-controls="thumb-item-1" aria-selected="true">
    1st item
  </a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-thumb" id="2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#thumb-item-2" role="tab" aria-controls="thumb-item-2" aria-selected="false">
    2nd item
  </a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-link-thumb" id="3-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#thumb-item-3" role="tab" aria-controls="thumb-item-3" aria-selected="false">
    3rd item
  </a>
</div>



<div class="tab-content" id="thumbcontent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="thumb-item-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="1-tab">
    1st content
    <div class="btn-container">
       <a class="next">next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="thumb-item-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="2-tab">
    2nd content
    <div class="btn-container">
       <a class="prev">prev</a>
       <a class="next">next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="thumb-item-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="3-tab">
    3rd content
    <div class="btn-container">
       <a class="prev">prev</a>
       <a class="next">next</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and this is for my JS :

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  $('#thumb-tabs > .active').next('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
  $('#thumb-tabs > .active').prev('a').trigger('click');
});
```

What I want to do is to hide the next button in the last tabs item, the thing is I create this dynamically using Wordpress and Toolset Views, so I cannot just delete the next button in the last item, so if there is a way to detect if it already reach the last item on the tabs it will trigger to hide the next button on that tabs content?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a common function to check if first or last tab is active and accordingly you can disable / hide previous and next button.

Please see below sample code

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  $('#thumb-tabs > .active').next('a').trigger('click');
  showHideButtons();
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
  $('#thumb-tabs > .active').prev('a').trigger('click');
  showHideButtons();
});

function showHideButtons() {
   //check if first tab is active
   if( $('#thumb-tabs > a:first').hasClass('active')){
       $('.prev').hide();
   } else{
       $('.prev').show();
   }
   //check if last tab is active
   if( $('#thumb-tabs > a:last').hasClass('active')){
       $('.next').hide();
   } else{
       $('.next').show();
   }
}
```

You can call `showHideButtons()` function on click of tab as well so that next and previous button will get hide show.

Comment: in the initial load same function can be called so that respective button can be hide

Comment: thats what i mentioned, it is common function and can be called whereever required